# Connecting IOS Device to IBM DB2 using JDBC Bridge

Tags: ios, jdbc, db2, jdbc-odbc, odbc-bridge

i'm having basic questions about the functionality of JDBC.
My IOS App needs a db2 connection. Since the IOS SDK dont have a db2-odbc connectivity i need a bridge to translate db2 commands to JSON/XML and vice versa.
Is it possible to realise a java application acting as the target for my IOS App and forwarding everything to the db2 server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to realise such an application. IBM Data Studio allows you to generate a REST or SOAP-based web service that you can then deploy in a Java container of your choice. [More details on IBM DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/dm0711pauser/).

Comment: Well this isn't the answer i was looking for.
In my opinion there is a much easier way to do this:
Using the JDBC driver for DB2 and communicating between java and objective c with stream socket

Comment: Well, if you already know the answer, then why do you ask the question?

Comment: Maybe there is a easier way for my needs.
No offense, but your reply was more like: yeah it's surely doable somehow, check out google if you want to know how

Comment: Your question was "is it possible?", and I gave you the answer to your exact question. If you're not happy, may be you should have asked a different question.